# Rotating Branes and AdS/CFT

Tags: string-theory, ads-cft, branes, holographic-principle

1. Do we have an extension of the AdS/CFT correspondence for rotating branes?
2. Are the rotating branes, the supergravity analog of the Kerr Black Holes in General Relativity?
3. What are the most successful applications in [Holography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography) for these branes?